# change background color of dynamic element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new in JavaScript, 
I have created two dynamic div using JavaScript. When I click on first div it becomes active. I want the div background color to be changed when I click on it, then is when it shoulde become active. When I click on second div, the second div should change background color and first div takes back it original color.

I want change bgcolor of btnCage and btnMice when i click on simultaneously.

```
var buttonDiv= document.createElement('div');

var btnCage = document.createElement('div');
btnCage.id = 'btnCage';
//btnCage.className = 'active';
btnCage.innerHTML = 'By Cages';
buttonDiv.appendChild(btnCage);
btnCage.onclick = function() {
     getMonthlyCensusCages()
}

var btnMice = document.createElement('div');
btnMice.id = 'btnMice';
//btnMice.className = 'active';
btnMice.innerHTML = 'By Mice';
buttonDiv.appendChild(btnMice);
btnMice.onclick = function() {
     getMonthlyCensus()
}
```

Please help me

Comment: why did you tag it as [tag:jquery]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in this way:

```
btnMice.onclick = function() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
   btnCage.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
}; 

btnCage.onclick = function() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
   btnMice.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
};
```

Comment: I have already implemented this, but it gave same bgcolor for both div, i want different bgcolor for onclick and offclick event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttonDiv= document.createElement('div');

var btnCage = document.createElement('div');
btnCage.id = 'btnCage';
//btnCage.className = 'active';
btnCage.innerHTML = 'By Cages';
buttonDiv.appendChild(btnCage);

var btnMice = document.createElement('div');
btnMice.id = 'btnMice';
//btnMice.className = 'active';
btnMice.innerHTML = 'By Mice';
buttonDiv.appendChild(btnMice);

// change style or change className
btnCage.onclick = function() {
     this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
     btnMice.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
     getMonthlyCensusCages();
}

btnMice.onclick = function() {
     this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
     btnCage.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
     getMonthlyCensus();
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented this, but it gave same bgcolor for both div, i want different bgcolor for onclick and offclick event

Comment: @PeeVee You mean onmousedown and onmouseout events?

Comment: When i click on div its bgcolor changes until i select another div